# SQL Server deleting records with invalid query

Tags: sql-server

I recently ran a query in SQL Server with invalid SQL included in the statement that inadvertently deleted all records in a table. The query (well an approximation of it) follows. I really don't understand how this could possibly happen because the query should have given me an error. The 'Select blah from testtable2' is an invalid statement. I'm hoping that someone could explain how this is a valid query and why it even runs. The result is that all rows from testtable1 are deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [blah] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable2](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
insert into testtable1 (id, blah) values (1, 1)
insert into testtable1 (id, blah) values (2, 2)

insert into testtable2 (id) values (1)
insert into testtable2 (id) values (2)

delete from testtable1 where id in (select blah from testtable2)
```

Comment: try select blah from testtable2 (blah doesn't exist in the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from testtable1 where id in (select blah from testtable2)
```

While `blah` does not exist in `testtable2` there is no error because it does exist in the outer query (`testtable1`) so the statement is fine.

```
delete from testtable1 where id in (select xblah from testtable2)
```

would fail as `xblah` does not exist in either, ditto for a qualified name:

```
delete from testtable1 where id in (select T.blah from testtable2 T)
```

Comment: I kind of get what you're saying, but I still don't understand how I can select a column that doesn't exist in an inner query when it is a definite select from a table. However I'll mark it as answered, and have learnt an important lesson. :)

Comment: `select blah from testtable2, testtable1` would give `1,1,2,2` - For each `blah` in `testtable1` also get a row from `testtable2`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

it only deletes them because of the match between id and blah in your data, you have effectively said

```
delete from testtable1 where id in (blah, blah)
```

id happens to match blah, for each row in testtable2, you have selected blah from table1

- change DELETE to SELECT and see what happens if id doesn't equal blah